# PDCurses Hanging on Input After Loop

Tags: c, input, pdcurses

While I was building a PDCurses application, I came across an issue where while I was waiting for input, it would just hang and not pass any data along to the program, even though it was still technically reading input. I managed to boil it down to the following code:

```
#include <curses.h>

main()
{
    initscr(); // initialize screen
    noecho(); // don't echo the keys to the screen
    cbreak(); // no waiting for enter key
    clear(); // clear screen

    while (getch() != 13) // loop until they press ENTER
        mvaddch(0, 0, 'a'); // GETS PAST HERE

    getch(); // HANGS; WINDOWS IS RECEIVING INPUT FROM THE KEYBOARD (turn off noecho()), BUT NEVER RETURNS IT TO THE ACTUAL PROGRAM

    return 0;
}
```

To put it in context as to how this was displayed in my program, I had a loop in `main()` that infinitely called a function that would display a menu until the ENTER key was pressed. However, if the user pressed a specific key while in the menu, it would call another menu and get input from that function. In the above code, I simplified it by just having two subsequent `getch()` calls.

My question is, why does it hang only after a loop checking for the ENTER key?? Shouldn't this be a simple thing?

Also, my PDCurses application is running on the Windows cmd. (13 = ENTER; KEY_ENTER does not work here)

Comment: "*I HAVE PROVEN IT GETS PAST HERE; YOU CAN ADD YOUR OWN VERIFICATION IF YOU LIKE*" That's not how it works. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene Ok, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the ENTER key makes `getch()` return 10 (LF), not 13 (CR). Thus, the second `getch()` is never reached. This is not specific to PDCurses or to Windows. You can change PDCurses' behavior in this regard by calling `raw()`, but that *may* be PDCurses-specific.

Comment: Actually, `nonl()` would be a more portable way to achieve a similar effect as `raw()`.